# Javascript 'confirm()' Cancelling Post Back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

On an asp.net 3.5 page, I have multiple textboxes that fire async postbacks on the TextChanged event as the user progresses through the form.  After the user completes the form a "Submit" button is pressed to submit the form which contains a javascript "confirm" dialog.  Everything works fine as long as the user has TABBED off all the fields.  However if a user changes the value of one of the textboxes and clicks the button w/o exiting the textbox, the "onClientClick" fires but if there's a "confirm" specificed the page does not postback:

```
onClientClick = return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');  //Page Does Not Post
```

However removing the confirm on the page does postback:

```
onClientClick = return true; //Page Posts
```

The button is a `<asp:PostBackTrigger/>`.  the textboxes' `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger/>`s are in the same updatepanel as the button.  I've tried moving them to another updatepanel as well w/ the same result.

Again, this is ONLY if the user has made a change in the textbox and does NOT tab off before clicking the button.  Tabbing off the box works just fine.  I've even put code to wait 5 seconds before displaying the confirm then submitting the form but same result (except having to wait 5 secs before confirming):

```
var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 5000);
while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');
```

Any ideas or decent workarounds??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: where did you put your brakpoint? in Page_Load or in TextChanged?

Comment: do you want to do a postback on Click irrespective of confirm() outcome?

Comment: @ARS i suppose he wants a postback only on YES.. or 'confirm' will never work

Comment: correct.  i only want to post back on 'OK".  however that's not happening right now.  it's only when a textbox has changed the button is clicked before the textbox has been tabbed off of

Comment: @greco my breakpoint was in the button_click handler.  i moved it to the page_load and it gets hit by the TextBox update and my click (even the onClientClick) is ignored completely.  i'm guessing this is a timing issue w/ the page not liking a button click while it's waiting on the response from the UpdatePanel.

Comment: can you post the HTML for the Button?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the better way to solve your issue without even writing a function.

```
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClick="BtnSubmit_Click"
   OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to Submit?')) return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

figured out a workaround.

```
function ConfirmSubmit(){
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?')){
      __doPostBack(btnSend, '');
   }
   return false;
}
```

here's the button:

```
<asp:Button id='btnSend' runat='server' onClientClick='return ConfirmSubmit();' />
```

Comment: I have had this problem for ages. I was against this idea because I don't like doing manual postbacks. However for my situation this fixed it. I was storing the confirm result into a var. Then doing stuff based on that var. However it would never return to the server. No matter what I tried. Adding a __doPostBack solved it though. So that is a win in my books.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function DummyFunction()
{
var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dt.getTime() + 5000);
while (new Date().getTime() < dt.getTime());
return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');
}
```

Update the code of onClientClick = "var result = DummyFunction(); return result;"

Comment: thank you but nope.  same result.  no matter where i put the confirm, it cancels the button submit.  again, it's only happens if the button is clicked without tabbing off the changed textbox.